# Suggest on a field that is the concatenation of other existing fields

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I have azure cosmosdb database which contains a user collection User (id, login, firstname, lastname, etc.).

I am using Azure cognitive search index to search/suggest over users and other collections.

My use case appears very simple, but I'm not finding the best way to solve it.

I want to make suggestions not only on the user first and last name but also on the fullname, which is a property not present in the database schema and can be the concatenation of the firstname + lastname or lastname + firstname.

For example, if I have a user named "John Doe", typing "John" , "Doe John," or "Doe" should return the same user.

Index fields

```
{
            "name": "user_first_name",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": false,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "facetable": false,
            "key": false,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": null,
            "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
            "normalizer": null,
            "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
            "name": "user_last_name",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": false,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "facetable": false,
            "key": false,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": null,
            "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
            "normalizer": null,
            "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
            "name": "user_full_name",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": false,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": false,
            "facetable": false,
            "key": false,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": null,
            "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
            "normalizer": null,
            "synonymMaps": []
        },
```

I've tried the Skillset MergeSkillset but can't get a successful result:

```
{
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.MergeSkill",
      "name": "skillset_users_merge_fullname",
      "description": "",
      "context": "/document",
      "insertPreTag": "",
      "insertPostTag": " ",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/user_first_name"
        },
        {
          "name": "itemsToInsert",
          "source": "/document/user_last_name"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "mergedText",
          "targetName": "user_full_name"
        }
      ]
    }
```

There is also another alternative that I have found, which is the synonymMaps but it can't be applied in my use case as iI have more than 20k users and the synonym maps don't allow more than 20k rules.

What is the best way to do this kind of suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly not optimal, but one way to do it is to use a custom skill that does the concatenation.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not optimal.

Comment: so there is nothing built-in that can make this work?

Comment: There's always overhead in using a custom skill: you need to create and manage your own function, and the indexer has to query an external resource on every document. This is especially suboptimal in such a simple case.
No, there is currently no other way of doing this although it may be added in the future.

Comment: Thank for the clear answer. So it would better to use /search api instead of /suggest for such a case?

Comment: Not sure about what the question is about search and suggest.