# Concatenating two string fields in azure search indexing pipeline

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm using azure search service and my indexer uses skillset to process json documents that come from blob storage. I have two string fields which I would like to concatenate. Can I do that?

I tried [text merger skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-textmerger) but it's purpose feels different (mergin array of values, not concatenating two fields). I also looked at [shaper skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-shaper) but it's not covering such case. Also [annotation language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-annotation-language) reference page doesn't mention such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of [Suggest on a field that is the concatenation of other existing fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76189738/suggest-on-a-field-that-is-the-concatenation-of-other-existing-fields/76204994#76204994) . Essentially, there is no current built in way to concatenate two string fields, and the only way would be to write a custom skill that does it for you. We understand this is not optimal for such a simple task, and we will consider adding it as a built in feature in the future.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer. Definitely worth adding, I had at least two use-cases when I needed it but found some workaround not having time to investigate it further.